# Is running ARM32 neon code on the iPhone 6 slow?

Tags: iphone, assembly, arm, 32-bit, neon

I have some neon optimized code that is compiled to armv7 assembly for the iPhone. Generation of arm64 code is **not** enabled.

Does the neon code provide any speed benefit on the newer iPhones (like iPhone 5s, 6plus) or could it run even slower than non neon code, since the 64bit processor has to somehow emulate the arm32 neon instructions?

Comment: Current ARMv8 hardware "emulates" 32-bit code by executing it. Natively. In AArch32 state ;)

Comment: Does this also apply for NEON instructions like VMUL etc.? I thought there are some differences in the registers etc. available in 64-bit mode...

Comment: Yes, AArch64 state has a different register layout, a completely different instruction set, new exception model, etc., but that's of little relevance to legacy processes running in AArch32 state, which presents itself as a minor evolution of ARMv7. My point is that there's no reason for an A32 NEON instruction to be any slower than the equivalent A64 SIMD instruction when it's the same operations going through the same execution units. In future, when legacy code is rare enough that new CPUs don't implement AArch32, _then_ emulation/DBT becomes a concern.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the infos! If you add it to an answer, I can accept it :)